# Rails Association and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

If I wanted to have a "user_type" column in my "users" table that references to another table called "user_type", how do I write the correct association in rails? For example if my user_type is 1 and 1 is admin in my user_types table, and when I write this in my rails console

```
user = User.first
user.user_type #I want this to return admin
```

I've tried with

```
class AddTypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :user_type, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

But it won't work

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should define the model associations.

```
class UserType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_type
end
```

You should read once this [association_basics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html) guide to understand how associations works in Rails.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this one if I type `user.user_type = 1` it will return `UserType expected, got 1 which is an instance of integer` how do I solve this?

Comment: `user.user_type_id = 1` you need to do, else `user.user_type = <it should be a UserType>` object. `add_reference` method added a `user_type_id` column to the `users` table, check the schema.rb file.

Comment: @JohnNuno One thing I'd say here is that, it makes sense more `UserRole`, not `UserType` IMO :)